# Pittsburgh English - dropping the "to be" before a verb

Tags: dialects

This is a region dialect issue, while discussing local idiosyncrasies the question came up is the following sentence grammatically correct with or without the "to be"

**"The clothes on the line need to be dried"**

In Pittsburgh, the regional dialect causes the "to be" to be dropped from speech.

**"The clothes on the line need dried"**

Although understood by the community and speaker, is this valid english?

Comment: This is not just Pennsylvania English. This is widely spread in the US. Note that _need drying_ would be just fine; the present instead of the perfect participle after _need_. There has been a large change in English syntax over the last couple of centuries, centered on non-tensed verb usages; thousands of new and old constructions co-existing. This is an old one, preserved all through the American Midwest. The classic example is the joke line, ideally written by a finger in the dust on a car's rear window: _This car needs washed_.

Comment: From where I live in the US (Midwest), and I've been around the block a few times, I've never heard "need dried" or similar version omitting the "to be" - nor have I ever seen "This car needs washed", @JohnLawler.  Around here we see "Wash me!" :-)